# JAX-RS failed to inject @EJB or @Inject

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3, jax-rs, inject

I'm trying to test a minimal JAX-RS + EJB/CDI injection mechanism and currently hitting a road-block due to GlassFish unable to inject for whatever reason.

(Using @Inject will throw NPE because GlassFish cannot inject the POJO).

My beans.xml contains only

`<beans />`

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
  <display-name>This is a REST Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here's the JAX-RS Resource class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @EJB
    ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl employeeService;

    @Path("/all")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Employee> index() {
        return this.employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }

}
```

Last but not least, the actual EJB:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
public class ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    final List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl() {
        final Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmployeeId(new Date().getTime());
        employee.setFirstName("FirstName-" + employee.getEmployeeId());
        employee.setMiddleName("MiddleName-" + employee.getEmployeeId());
        employee.setLastName("LastName-" + employee.getEmployeeId());
        employee.setScoped("ApplicationScoped");
        this.employees.add(employee);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }
}
```

And this is the exception from GlassFish

```
[#|2011-05-13T12:37:53.584-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=107;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Portable JNDI names for EJB EmployeeResource : [java:global/rest-inject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/EmployeeResource!com.pcis.example.java.rest.resources.EmployeeResource, java:global/rest-inject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/EmployeeResource]|#]

[#|2011-05-13T12:37:53.610-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=107;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Portable JNDI names for EJB ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl : [java:global/rest-inject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl!com.pcis.example.java.rest.resources.EmployeeService, java:global/rest-inject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl]|#]

[#|2011-05-13T12:37:53.641-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-05-13T12:37:53.898-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:234)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5268)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2798)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2685)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:734)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:1981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2796)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.getManager(WeldBootstrap.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:428)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:300)
    ... 86 more
|#]
```

Would anyone know if there's a problem with JAX-RS and GF 3.1?

The code works if it is a Servlet though :)

Comment: I would open a bug report with Glassfish or Weld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Jersey does not handle properly dependency injection.  So far it seems to be reported and aimed for future releases. http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-517

Facing same issue I had to implement context lookup to get access to managed resource.

So try something like this in your WS constructor:

```
employeeService = (ApplicationScopedEmployeeServiceImpl) new
                   InitialContext().lookup("java:global/EJB/EmployeeService");
```

Comment: I suppose I can have 2 constructors: one that initialize via lookup() and the other that inject it (for testing purpose). Thanks for letting me know that this is a known bug.

Comment: I took my words back. I managed to make this work now by doing 2 things: 1) Deploy a simple REST project with the following characteristics: 1 simple EJB with no interface, 1 Simple REST resource class that returns a string from the EJB. 2) Eclipse Project clean on the above set of files and "mvn clean install". One of the tools: either GlassFish, Maven, or Eclipse are tripping