# How can I get rid of those Omnifaces deployment exceptions?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, omnifaces

I'm currently getting in touch with a part of our application that have been developped by a team that is now defunct, and encountering strange issues.

This application is deployed as an EAR, containing an EJB-JAR and three distinct web-applications (one for SOAP services, one for web UI, and so on, ...).

When trying to deploy that application, i'm having constant deploy errors like the following

```
[#|2013-12-31T11:05:45.236+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5329)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4806)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2740)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializerListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:749)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:1987)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2851)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:299)
    ... 51 more
```

Application is deployed on a Glassfish 3.1.1 and that exception totally prevents the EAR from being deployed. How can i fix it ?

I've read this very component has for sole role to allow Omnifaces [FacesView](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/facesviews/package-summary.html) to work. But we don't use that feature. So how can I totally p^revent it from being loaded ?.

**[EDIT 1]** In a fascinating fashion, removing Jersey (acccording to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5997008/15619), Jersey CDI moden doesn't seem to work well with classical ones) from that web project moved the error to an other omnifaces component. Error is now

```
[#|2013-12-31T11:32:50.558+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.component.output.cache.CacheInitializerListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.component.output.cache.CacheInitializerListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5329)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.component.output.cache.CacheInitializerListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4806)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2740)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.omnifaces.component.output.cache.CacheInitializerListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:749)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:1987)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2851)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:299)
    ... 51 more
|#]
```

Quite similar, no ?

**[EDIT 2]** Notice that, according to [this answer regarding a similar error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912503/15619), all my web dependencies are in my web/jsf project's WEB-INF/lib folder. Those dependencies are ... FEAR ...

- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- cssparser-0.9.5.jar
- gson-2.2.2.jar
- <del>jsf-impl-2.1.2.jar</del> got rid of that one by using correct dependency version/scope
- omnifaces-1.6.3.jar
- openfaces-3.0.jar
- primefaces-3.4.1.jar
- richfaces-components-api-4.2.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-components-ui-4.2.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-api-4.2.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.2.3.Final.jar
- sac-1.3.jar

Comment: This is a bug in GF 3.1.1's CDI implementation. Which OminFaces version are you using? Since 1.6.3 there's a CDI extension which should veto those classes from being unnecessarily auto-registered as CDI managed beans. So, with OmniFaces 1.6.3 you shouldn't be seeing those exceptions at all (if the container's CDI implementation is doing its job well ...). Never seen those in GF 3.1.2.2, by the way, haven't ever tested it on 3.1.1.

Comment: @BalusC Like the edit 2 shows, I'm using omnifaces 1.6.3. And I've just checked Glassfishv ersion, which is `Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12)`

Comment: Why JSF impl in `/WEB-INF/lib`? GF has its own. Might as well be the cause.

Comment: @BalusC I removed it (by using Glassfish version and changing dependency scope to `provided`) but it changed nothing ... welll, nothing excepted I'm now back to first error message :-(

Comment: @BalusC I'm facing the same problem with 1.14 and Glassfish 3.1.2